# SQL Substring separation throws conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have to get the last four digits of credit card number, after separating this by substring function the result throws conversion error. Below is a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE REV (MEMO varchar(100),MEMO_TYPE varchar(100))
INSERT REV VALUES ('09999D,xxxxxxxxxxxx0999,xx/xx,   30.27', 'CREDCARD')
INSERT REV VALUES ('09999D,xxxxxxxxxxxx0666,xx/xx,   50.45', 'CREDCARD')
INSERT REV VALUES ('09999D,REVVALS,ALC,   0', 'OTHER')
```

Below is  the query  used

```
Select CAST(case when MEMO_TYPE = 'CREDCARD' then  
SUBSTRING(MEMO, CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)+1, LEN(MEMO)
-CHARINDEX(',', MEMO-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(MEMO))-6)) ELSE null END
as varchar(100))
-- as Cardnumber)
From REV
```

It throws
    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
    '09999D,xxxxxxxxxxxx0999,xx/xx, 30.27' to data type int.

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simple... Anyone care to enlighten?

Comment: You have the expression `MEMO - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(MEMO))`.  Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below query

```
Select 
case when MEMO_TYPE = 'CREDCARD' 
then SUBSTRING(MEMO, CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)+1, LEN(MEMO) - (CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(MEMO))-6)) ELSE null END
From REV
```

sorry just fixed conversion error with above query,
Please use below query for getting 4 digit card numbers..

```
Select 
case when MEMO_TYPE = 'CREDCARD' 
then replace(SUBSTRING(MEMO,charindex(',',MEMO)+1,len(MEMO) - charindex(',',reverse(MEMO),CHARINDEX(',',reverse(MEMO))+1) - charindex(',',MEMO)),'x','') ELSE null END
From REV
```

Comment: @Matt no, I just changed the syntax to avoid conversion error.with the latest query, I have tried and it gives only 4 digit numbers.

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks Nandish. I made few changes for my requirement.Select 
case when MEMO_TYPE = 'CREDCARD' 
then SUBSTRING(MEMO, CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)+1, LEN(MEMO)-CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)
-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(MEMO))) ELSE null END as CardNumber
From REV

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon is right, you have `MEMO - CHARINDEX(...)` which is a VARCHAR field minus an INT function result, which would result in the conversion failed message you are seeing.

Comment: @Dev: you are right, now i changed to LEN(MEMO) - (CHARINDEX(',', MEMO)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(MEMO))-6))  and it works.